# S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request during multi part upload using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to use boto to upload a large file using multi part upload.

Here's my code

```
import math, os
import boto.s3.connection
import boto
from filechunkio import FileChunkIO

# Connect to S3
c = boto.connect_s3()
b = c.get_bucket('bucketA')

# Get file info
source_path = './A/tmp1/'
source_size = os.stat(source_path).st_size

# Create a multipart upload request
mp = b.initiate_multipart_upload(os.path.basename(source_path))

# Use a chunk size of 50 MiB (feel free to change this)
chunk_size = 52428800
chunk_count = int(math.ceil(source_size / float(chunk_size)))

# Send the file parts, using FileChunkIO to create a file-like object
# that points to a certain byte range within the original file. We
# set bytes to never exceed the original file size.
for i in range(chunk_count):
    offset = chunk_size * i
    bytes = min(chunk_size, source_size - offset)
    with FileChunkIO(source_path, 'r', offset=offset, bytes=bytes) as fp:
        mp.upload_part_from_file(fp, part_num=i + 1)

# Finish the upload
mp.complete_upload()
```

My error stack is this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
S3ResponseError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-2cf74dccfef2> in <module>
     22 
     23 # Create a multipart upload request
---> 24 mp = b.initiate_multipart_upload(os.path.basename(source_path))
     25 
     26 # Use a chunk size of 50 MiB (feel free to change this)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py in initiate_multipart_upload(self, key_name, headers, reduced_redundancy, metadata, encrypt_key, policy)
   1766         else:
   1767             raise self.connection.provider.storage_response_error(
-> 1768                 response.status, response.reason, body)
   1769 
   1770     def complete_multipart_upload(self, key_name, upload_id,

S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Request Content-Type is not multipart/form-data</Message></Error>
```

Where exactly do I need to set the Request Content-Type?
I'm using boto due to certain dependency restrictions, will not be possible for me to upgrade to boto3.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

The [docs say](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.initiate_multipart_upload) the first argument is a `key_name`, ie the name of the file when it's available in the bucket.

It looks like you're passing in the name of a local directory `'./A/tmp1/'` and not a large file. I don't know if this is allowed or not. The S3 docs on key names aren't super clear.

The other part of the the [docs say](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.initiate_multipart_upload) which might be useful say the `initiate_multipart_upload` function takes a `headers` dictionary as an argument. These are standard http headers and a `Content-Type` header is a standard http header: [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type).

Comment: While this is certainly helpful, the documentation is not clear on how to add the headers. This is what I used `mp = b.initiate_multipart_upload(os.path.basename(source_path), headers={'Content-Type':"multipart/form-data"})`
However, the error that is thrown is that Missing multipart boundary specification. I then modified the header as `headers={'Content-Type':"multipart/form-data; boundary=---"}` But no luck, I received the boundary not found error.

Comment: I'm still not 100 percent sure you can upload a whole directory. Are you trying to upload every file?